# NET 6, Net Framework C#. Требуется создать файл bmp с текстом на самой картинке и штрихкодом

Tags: c#

Библиотеку по созданию штрихкода я уже нашёл. Код нормально генерируется, а вот каким образом я могу в картинку дописать информацию (это будет определённый текст и несколько чисел) в определённых участках картинки - найти совсем не могу. Обязательно нужно, чтобы это было консольное приложение, которое можно будет использовать как в среде Windows так и в Linux.

На самом деле это я выбрал NET 6, такого требования не стоит. Поэтому если можно использовать классическое приложение net framework и оно будет работать в Linux тоже, то можно пример оттуда.

Мне нужен хотя бы пример, в котором дописывается произвольный текст в произвольном месте и всё это сохраняется в bmp.  Возможно тоже имеется спец. библиотека для такой задачи?

Искал информацию по форумам, но там только элипсы и квадраты рисуют, в добавок используют в основном элемент PictureBox, а это уже виндовые формы.

Comment: в этой теме обсуждали что-то подобное: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192431/drawing-text-on-image

Comment: net framework  - это только Windows

Comment: [.NET Core Image Processing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-image-processing/) - здесь описаны несколько библиотек